# Icon not highlighted when using BottomBarPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I’m using the `BottomBarPage` package. I’m changing the Tab on the fly programmatically, however the icon at the bottom doesn’t get highlighted for Android when there’s a tab change. It works well on iOS on the hand.
I tried James Montemagno’s code, I couldn’t get it to work with the `BottomBarPage` package.
This is the link to his code
https://montemagno.com/dynamically-changing-xamarin-forms-tab-icons-when-select/

How do I get the Icon highlighted when there is a Tab Page happening programmatically for `BottomBarPage`?

Below is my code.

```cs
public AndroidMainPage(int indexPage)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    CurrentPageChanged += MainPage_CurrentPageChanged;
    CurrentPage = Children[indexPage];
    CurrentPage.Appearing += (s, a) => Children[indexPage].Icon = new FileImageSource() { File = "quizzes_selected.png" };
    CurrentPage.Disappearing += (s, a) => Children[indexPage].Icon = new FileImageSource() { File = "quizzes.png" };
    _currentPage = CurrentPage;
}

private void MainPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IIconChange currentBinding;
    if (_currentPage != null)
    {
        currentBinding = ((NavigationPage)_currentPage).CurrentPage.BindingContext as IIconChange;
        if (currentBinding != null)
            currentBinding.IsSelected = false;
    }

    _currentPage = CurrentPage;
    currentBinding = ((NavigationPage)_currentPage).CurrentPage.BindingContext as IIconChange;
    if (currentBinding != null)
        currentBinding.IsSelected = true;

    UpdateIcons?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Android BottomBarPage Renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AndroidMainPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace TabPageDemo.Android.Renderers
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : BottomBarPageRenderer
    {
        bool setup;
        TabLayout layout;

        public MyTabbedPageRenderer()
        {    
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BottomBarPage> e)
        {
            if (e != null) base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Element != null)
            {
                ((AndroidMainPage)Element).UpdateIcons += Handle_UpdateIcons;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (layout == null && e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
            {
                layout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
            }
        }

        void Handle_UpdateIcons(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabLayout tabs = layout;

            if (tabs == null)
                return;

            for (var i = 0; i < Element.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                var child = Element.Children[i].BindingContext as IIconChange;
                if (child == null) continue;
                var icon = child.CurrentIcon;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(icon))
                    continue;

                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.GetTabAt(i);
                SetCurrentTabIcon(tab, icon);
            }
        }

        void SetCurrentTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, string icon)
        {
            tab.SetIcon(IdFromTitle(icon, ResourceManager.DrawableClass));
        }

        int IdFromTitle(string title, Type type)
        {
            string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(title);
            int id = GetId(type, name);
            return id;
        }

        int GetId(Type type, string memberName)
        {
            object value = type.GetFields().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == memberName)?.GetValue(type)
                ?? type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == memberName)?.GetValue(type);
            if (value is int)
                return (int)value;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the Renderer, the tab variable is always null from this `TabLayout.Tab tab = tabs.GetTabAt(i);`

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can't just copy someone else's code and expect it to work with an entirely different control. When using bottom tabs, the class is a _different_ one. You need to adopt the code from the blog post to fit.

Comment: I did, the one he had inherited from the TabbedPageRenderer, mine inherits from the BottomBarPageRenderer. Any insights?